# Constraints on arguments to data constructor

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define a data type for storing RGB values

```
data Color = RGB Int Int Int

black = RGB 0 0 0
```

However since parameters always lie in range `[0-255]`, is there a way to constrain arguments to data constructor such that value is always a valid color?

Comment: Well, you can just use `Word8` instead of `Int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments indicate, you can use [`Word8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Word.html#t:Word8), which has the desired range.

```
import Data.Word(Word8)

data Color = Color Word8 Word8 Word8
```

`Word8` implements `Num` so you can use regular integer constants with it.

The more general solution to the problem "I have a constraint that can't be expressed with types" is to hide your constructor and make a checked interface. In your case, that would manifest as

```
data Color = Color Int Int Int -- Don't export the constructor

color :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Color
color r g b
 | r < 256 && g < 256 && b < 256 = Just (Color r g b)
 | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: see also: [Smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) (that's what the second solution mentioned in this answer is usually called)

Comment: These days there's an even smarter/prettier way to make smart constructors: use an explicitly bi-directional pattern synonym https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.10.4/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pattern-synonyms, call it `Color` (upper case), call the constructor in the datatype something else, and don't export it, as the answer says.

Answer (score -2):

[GADT's might help with this](https://wiki.haskell.org/GADTs_for_dummies)

I'm unsure if it will work like this. but with some typeclass arithmetic it might be possible